# regex replace group (java, python, perl, awk)

Tags: regex, replace, grouping, regex-group

I'm looking for a way to do a replace based on a regex with grouping but that only would replace the group. For instance, if I have:

```
string = "xxxab yyyyab zzzab xxab"
```

I want to call something like:

```
replace_all_group(string, /xx(ab)/,"AB")
```

and obtain:

```
string = "xxxAB yyyyab zzzab xxAB"
```

any "short" solution in java, perl, python and awk is very welcome! so far I was able to achieve that using index_of and the like, but I'm hoping there's some kind of one-liner somewhere out there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Match and replace `ab` **only if it is preceded by** `xx`.

You can use the following regex to match such an `ab`:

```
(?<=xx)ab
```

[Working example in Perl](http://www.ideone.com/Wv082)

[Working example in Java](http://www.ideone.com/DVCHW)

Comment: I see, that is exactly what i was looking for. i've been meaning to look into these lookaround but did not know what it was actually doing. thanks a lot!

Comment: @codaddict, can you post the actual example code?  These links appear to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

If the string won't get more complicated:

```
>>> re.sub("xxab", "xxAB", "xxxab yyyyab zzzab xxab")
'xxxAB yyyyab zzzab xxAB'
```

Or a python version of @codaddict's answer:

```
>>> re.sub("(?<=xx)ab", "AB", "xxxab yyyyab zzzab xxab")
'xxxAB yyyyab zzzab xxAB'
```